# Открыть URL и установить Cookie

Tags: android, cookie, android-intent

Нужно открыть страницу и передать ей cookie из приложения:

Открываю страницу стандартно:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(_url));
_view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Cookie:

```
portalaliasid=blabla
```

Как я понял, можно через EXTRA_HEADERS установить?

**UPD.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("portalaliasid",AfterLogin.loginCookies.get("portalaliasid"));
    intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, bundle);
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Вроде cookie устанавливаются, но не могу это проверить, крашится браузер, если захожу в настройки... изначально, с помощью JSOUP библиотеки получаю эти кукисы, но наверное из-за user-agent'a они не совпадают... как узнать user agent стандартного браузера?

**UPD 2.**

```
System.getProperty("http.agent")
```

выдает 
**Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1; Android SDK built for x86 Build/LKY45)**
А в самом браузере user agent

```
Mozila/5.0 (linux; .....
```

Comment: cookie не передается, попробовал вручную на PC установить, проходят валидацию без user agent...  Как передать можно по-другому, чтобы работало?